# Logging with multiprocessing in Docker

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Amazon CloudWatch for logging using the built in logging in Python with a CloudWatch handler added. My problem is that when trying to set up logging for a processes the handler isn't added in a docker environment but it works fine running locally.

Example code:

`main.py`

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from logger import logger
from worker import worker

def app():
    logger.info({'message': 'Main process started',
                'pid': os.getpid()})
    p1 = Process(target=worker)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    logger.info({'message': 'In main process',
                 'pid': os.getpid()})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

`worker.py`

```
import os

def worker():
    from logger import logger
    logger.info({'message': 'In worker process',
                 'pid': os.getpid()})
```

`logger.py`

```
import os
import logging
from watchtower import CloudWatchLogHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('foo-logger')

logger.addHandler(CloudWatchLogHandler())
logger.info({'message': 'CloudWatch handler added',
             'pid': os.getpid()})
```

My expected output (X is PID for main process and Y is pid for worker process). This is the output when I run the code locally.

```
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "CloudWatch handler added", "pid": X}
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "Main process started", "pid": X}
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "CloudWatch handler added", "pid": Y}
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "In worker process", "pid": Y}
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "In main process", "pid": X}
```

Actual output. This the output when running in Docker.

```
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "CloudWatch handler added", "pid": X}
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "Main process started", "pid": X}
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "In worker process", "pid": Y} <-- Before this line I want the handler to be added
INFO:foo-logger:{"message": "In main process", "pid": X}
```

Please explain what I'm not thinking of and how to work with logs in a multiprocessing program.

EDIT: After some more reserach I'm able to replicate Docker behaviour locally by setting `set_start_method('fork')` as it seems like my Mac is using the spawn-method instead of fork... As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) the fork method should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `set_start_method('spawn')`. More details about the cause of this issue and further explanation is found on the below two links:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue6721
- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/